# X won't start because /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 is a directory

Tags: x11, docker

Some days ago the startup process of the X server in my Debian 8 box broke. I'm unsure of what caused this situation, but it probably was either an apt-get upgrade or a rolled back attempt to install Nvidia drivers.

After every reboot /var/log/Xorg.0.log shows the following traces:

```
[    60.603] _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
[    60.603] _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
[    60.603] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    60.603] (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
[    60.603] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    60.603] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    60.603] (EE) 
[    60.603] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

The server is not running, but /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 exists and is a directory, instead of a socket. If I log in as root and execute

```
rmdir /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 ; service kdm restart
```

then the X server starts without problems.

Any idea on what might be going on and how to fix this problem so the X server can start without user intervention?

## EDIT 1

The following `find` commands didn't return any result (no output at all):

```
find /etc /var /usr -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep X11-unix | grep mkdir
find / -mount -path /dev -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep X11-unix | grep mkdir
```

So I added the `-a exit,always -S all -F dir=/tmp/.X11-unix` rule to `/etc/audit.rules`, which produced the following traces:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1495391670.743:93): arch=c000003e syscall=83 success=yes exit=0 a0=c2082a2420 a1=1ed a2=0 a3=0 items=2 ppid=1 pid=926 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="docker" exe="/usr/bin/docker" key=(null)
type=CWD msg=audit(1495391670.743:93):  cwd="/"
type=PATH msg=audit(1495391670.743:93): item=0 name="/tmp/.X11-unix/" inode=48365573 dev=fe:02 mode=041777 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT
type=PATH msg=audit(1495391670.743:93): item=1 name="/tmp/.X11-unix/X0" inode=48365588 dev=fe:02 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1495391670.743:93): proctitle=2F7573722F62696E2F646F636B6572002D64002D480066643A2F2F
```

A successful syscall 83 is a successful `mkdir`, isn't it? This question has become a Docker issue. In the past weeks I've started using `-volume /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix` in my containers to *dockerize* X11 applications. I don't understand, however, why it is creating the `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` directory, taking into account that I haven't specified the `X0` part in the path and also that those containers are started once the desktop is loaded, not before.

Is is possible that Docker is trying to restore the state of previously run containers? Anyone can provide any hint on how to prevent this?

Comment: Does this happen over and over?  If so, what triggers it?  A reboot?  Simply logging out and trying to log back in?

Comment: The `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` directory is consistently created during boot. Logging out, logging in, and restarting KDM work fine once the `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` directory is manually removed.

Comment: I'd guess that a bad script is creating the directory.  Run a search as root,  Something like `find /etc /var /usr -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep X11-unix | grep mkdir` should find it.  If not, `find / ...` will search *everything*...

Comment: Thanks for the hint @AndrewHenle. It seems that Docker is interfering with the X server startup. I've updated the question.

Comment: If you delay starting your Docker apps until X has already started, do they work properly?

Comment: The script that runs the Docker containers is executed as a startup application in KDE. I guess this happens after logging in, what can only happen after X server has started. My bet is that the Docker daemon starts before the X server, and then tries to restore some state from previously run containers.

Comment: Adding `x11-common` to the `Required-Start` of `/etc/init.d/docker` seemed to work (in the past few days the problem was random...). This is, however, a partial solution since I'm masking the real problem. I would like to know what is causing Docker to behave this way in the first place.